# Context menu after press on app icon

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, swift, contextmenu

Does custom apps support this feature today? Instagram support this feature for example.

Can you help me to add context menu to my app.
What shold I do to add context menu? And How can I handle it?
I tried to find this information in google/stackoverflow/documentation. But without some results. Only force touch on iWatch.

May be some link to documentation or article about this. May be it is not first question about this.

P.S.
Thank for attention and any help.
Thak

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/Adopting3DTouchOniPhone/3DTouchAPIs.html):

> iOS 9 supports Home screen static and dynamic quick actions.
>
> - **Static quick actions** are available to the user immediately upon app installation. Define Home screen static quick actions in your
>     app’s `Info.plist` file in the [`UIApplicationShortcutItems`](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/iPhoneOSKeys.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009252-SW36) array.
> - **Dynamic quick actions** are available to the user after first launch. Define Home screen dynamic quick actions with the
>     [UIApplicationShortcutItem](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIApplicationShortcutItem_class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/UIApplicationShortcutItem), [UIMutableApplicationShortcutItem](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIMutableApplicationShortcutItem_class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/UIMutableApplicationShortcutItem), and
>     [UIApplicationShortcutIcon](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIApplicationShortcutIcon_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/UIApplicationShortcutIcon) classes. Add dynamic quick actions to your
>     app’s shared [UIApplication](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIApplication_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/UIApplication) object using the [shortcutItems](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIApplication_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIApplication/shortcutItems) property.

Also available [sample application source code](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/samplecode/ApplicationShortcuts/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40016545).

Comment: Be aware: The guy that wrote the sample code did not really understand how to use enums in Swift.